# How to write spock test case for exception handling?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I am learning Spock so this may be very basic.

```java
public Random genRand() {
  try {
    return SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
  }
  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    return new SecureRandom();
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is:

```java
public void setup() {
  mockClassName = spy(ClassName)
  mockClassName.logger() >> mockLogger
}

def "exception test case"() {
  given: "nothing"

  when:"method call happens"
  mockClassName.genRand()

  then:"handle"
  SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()
}
```

This covers the try block only.

While trying:

```java
public void setup() {
  mockClassName = spy(ClassName)
  mockClassName.logger() >> mockLogger
}

def "exception test case"() {
  given: "nothing"
  SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong() >> Exception

  when:"method call happens"
  mockClassName.genRand()

  then:"catch"
  NoSuchAlgorithmException e = thrown()
  new SecureRandom()
}
```

This gives the error, expected exception of type `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException`, but no exception was thrown.

Is it possible to do both try and catch in one test case? Feel free to make two.

Comment: I have edited your question, making the previously messy code more readable. Please be informed that space and line break characters don't cost extra money here. You may use both indentation and line breaks in order to hurt other people's eyes less, if you so choose. I also added syntax highlighting. Please learn how to use both. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to test several branches of your code in one test, so doing it in two tests is actually the right approach. If you try to find a simple description of your test and have to describe several kinds of results, then that's a hint that your approach is not good.

A reminder, you should name your test methods with "It...", for example:

"It returns a default SecureRandom, if no strong instance of SecureRandom can be found"

Another point: You code never leaks a `NoSuchAlgorithmException` into Spec. This exception is caught in your production code, and then you retunr a valid `SecureRandom`.  You can only use `thrown()` if your code actually throws an exception, meaning this is a hard expectation. Your test will fail if the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, is there a way to write a test case for the catch block, without changing the existing code? I need coverage for that part.

Comment: Why don't you want to change it in order to make it more testable? You could factor out the `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` call into an extra method, calling it from `genRand()`, handling the exception there like before. Then you could stub that method in a spy for the error case, throwing an exception instead of returning a result. That would give you full coverage of all execution paths without the need to mock static methods of JDK classes. Feel free to ask, if youi do not understand my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting my own comment:

> Why don't you want to change the application code in order to make it more testable? You could factor out the `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` call into an extra method, calling it from `genRand()`, handling the exception there like before. Then you could stub that method in a spy for the error case, throwing an exception instead of returning a result. That would give you full coverage of all execution paths without the need to mock static methods of JDK classes.

I mean something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74797317;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomProvider {
  public Random genRand() {
    try {
      return getRandStrong();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      return new SecureRandom();
    }
  }

  protected SecureRandom getRandStrong() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74797317

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

class RandomProviderTest extends Specification {
  def "happy path"() {
    given:
    RandomProvider randomProvider = new RandomProvider()

    expect:
    randomProvider.genRand()
  }

  def "exception test case"() {
    given:
    RandomProvider randomProvider = Spy() {
      getRandStrong() >> { throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("oops") }
    }

    expect:
    randomProvider.genRand()
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJydU7FOwzAQ3fMVp07pYgmBVAECiYGBAYQIOzLONTEktjlf2kao_47tpqWBdoDFsn3v7t69Zzup3mWFUKLwirr2pZWekYTnELALpHljl-JjdjY7n52ezLJMt84Sg3dWvYtGmkoUDpWeayVZW7ONv8mFFB5VR5p78WCLTtU3TWXDsW5vVwpdQmeqkd7DkzSlbR_JLnSJ9IyeAVeMpvQwqg6fGQSqc5jU0rkenOR6kk_TNUClF2gu0nZcEGh8vAKDyx-YfJqlTFyFhrypMk4TFZqYE5DrbMsDt6MAR9ZKevwXocL1u7SQiBwTCiZrqnB_fQ2fwDXZZWJ-TM58Yq3zkymsU531HyaK6HX2N_cuD8OLuMHNwGNIx7oR20DmutdGKzj0ApIQQ3wTgR3VQSSmficXIXdkfqp2OYgQ1_B8VA35sUkAv7Uv-vABWoFEwpE23Jgcg1B8j96Hn5JPh8K7ttGR_Zn3OycLHFkODmA5gv0yOfnrj5o7EBya7leK7O5M-LFG4f7w0dEv_PdN7A).

In my IDE, the coverage view looks like this:

[image: Coverage report]

[image: Class under test with covered methods highlighted]